# Android button not opening other class

Tags: java, android, button

I have problems with buttons.I have made 2 buttons that will when pressed open other activity(class).In code there is no error but when I launch emulator it just doesn't work and isn't opening those classes.
My button's btnopis and btnpronadi don't work(they are not opening other activity(class)).But I have button exit that Works and closes app. I don't get where the problem is. Here is the code

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    izlaz();
}
public Button btnopis;
    public void otvoriopis(){
        btnopis=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnopis);
        btnopis.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent otvoriopis= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Opis.class);
                startActivity(otvoriopis);
            }
        });

    }
public Button btnpronadi;
    public void otvoripronadi(){
        btnpronadi=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnpronadi);
        btnpronadi.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent otvoripronadi= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Pronadi.class);
                startActivity(otvoripronadi);
        }
    });
}
public Button btnizlaz;
    public void izlaz(){
        btnizlaz=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnizlaz);
        btnizlaz.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

here is the manifest code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.shromid">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/app_ikona"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/app_icon_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:label="ShromID"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".Opis" />
        <activity android:name=".Pronadi"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you declared those activities in manifest?

Comment: Yes I did, I will add manifest code now.

Comment: No need for manifest. Check my answer

Comment: your methods are not working bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot do call `otvoriopis()` and `otvoripronadi()` at `onCreate`:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    izlaz();

    otvoriopis();
    otvoripronadi();
}
```

Comment: I can accept it in 8 minutes. As soon as I will be able to accept it, I'll do it :)

Answer (score 0):

You should call your functions in onCreate method, like you did for 'izlaz'